# Send AT Command to module that is not working as HOST (does not show /dev/ttyUSB paths)

Tags: at-command, modem, lte, minicom

I was doing some experiments with a 5G module (STIM8200EA-M2) and sent the `AT+CPCIEMODE=PE` that set the module to PE mode (I don't know what is the meaning of that).

The problem is that now I can't see the module in the traditional `/dev/ttyUSB*` paths, witch means I can't connect to it with minicom and reverse what I did (set it back as HOST).

How can I send a single AT command for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I end up finding out how to get back the `/dev/ttyUSB*` ports. I had to add the module ID to the USB serial drivers.

With `lsusb` you can get the ID and then in root mode you just do:

```
echo "05c6 901f" > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

(replace the `:` from the ID with a whitespace)